# Get record from dataset using condition

Tags: c#, dataset

I want to get some record between fromdate to todate from dataset. But the both fromdate and todate in the same column ..

```
 **Expression :** 
  string expression = "punchDate >='" + txtfromdate.Text + "' and PunchDate <='" + txttodate.Text + "' ";
            findbyexpression(expression);
```

this expression return records in a same month. suppose i want to get records from '12-02-2011' to 10-01-2011' means it doesn't returns records...

```
 protected void findbyexpression(string Expression)
{
    try
    {
        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
        DataSet4TableAdapters.sp_getalltimesheetTableAdapter TA = new DataSet4TableAdapters.sp_getalltimesheetTableAdapter();
        DataSet4.sp_getalltimesheetDataTable DS = TA.GetData();
        DataTable DT = new DataTable();
        DT = DS[0].Table;
        DataRow[] foundRows;
        foundRows = DT.Select(Expression);
        dt1 = foundRows.CopyToDataTable();
        Session["TaskTable"] = dt1;
        grdvw.DataSource = Session["TaskTable"];
        grdvw.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception e2)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "temp", "<script language='javascript'>alert('" + e2.Message + "');</script>", false);
    }
}
```

Comment: your question text: from '12-02-2011' to 10-01-2011' means it doesn't returns records...says the from date is > to date but normally from date has to be less than or equal to the to date..I hope you phrased your question text correctly..

Comment: Suppose from date : 01-01-2012 and todate 10-01-2011 means it returns correct record. then From date :01-11-2011 Todate : 10-01-2011 means it doesn't get any record. Actually the between date contain some records..please help me ..

Answer (score 0):

```
    string expression = string.Format("punchDate>=convert(datetime,'{0}',105) and PunchDate <=convert(datetime,'{1}',105) ", txtfromdate.Text,txttodate.Text);
```

//this may be work！